# Buffering Gridview android

Tags: android, gridview, buffer

My Gridview prepare only the visible items, so when i scroll to an item which were not visible, it's prepared instantly, My visible items are 9 (Gridview with 3 columns), could i prepare 3 views in advance when i scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying large set of views are done efficiently done in android.Therefore the GridView only creates views (widget) if needed and attach them to the view hierarchy.The default Adapter implementation for a GridView will recycle views, e.g. if a row is not displayed anymore it will be recycled and only its content will change. If you implement your own adapter for a view you also should do this to avoid performance problems.I mean you should re-use convertview returned in Adoptors getView function.